# No se compila correctamente java en NetBeans

Tags: java, poo, netbeans, compilar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba practicando un poco de POO en java y al momento de compilar me salta este erro.

no se porque dice que me salta este error, realmente he revisado el codigo pero tal vez no lo suficiente,

Comment: El constructor de tu clase coche requiere 3 parámetros, un int y dos String, que es exactamente lo que dice el error también. Estás intentando instanciarlo sin ningún valor... no te va a dejar, porque no tienes un constructor sin parámetros!

Comment: eso me crea entonces otra pregunta, como logro hacer que mi contructor contenga los parametros?

Comment: `COCHE car = new COCHE(230,"Mustang","verde");` y evidentemente ya no requieres las 3 líneas que vienen a continuación (los *setters*) ya que has seteado en el constructor

Comment: Lo otro que en la clase `COCHE` agregues un segundo constructor `public COCHE(){}`

Comment: Ok, He agregado el segundo constructor, y he puesto los parametros en el contructor COCHE, ahora de nuevo al intentar compilar me lanza el error: Command execution failed, de paso no encuentra ni carga la clase principal

Comment: Te recomiendo que repases los ejercicios previos. Como has podido comprobar, copiar y pegar código sin saber qué hace cada cosa no sirve de mucho para avanzar.  Los fallos que tienes son por falta de base, cosas básicas de POO y de java. Eso no podemos enseñártelo, tienes que repasar, hacer los ejercicios uno a uno desde el principio para afianzar la base antes de poder hacer otras cosas. Aquí no podemos llevarte de la mano con cada error (no tenemos detalles ni acceso a lo que estás haciendo, ni es la finalidad del sitio)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.